# How to pass values as parameters from a main report to a subreport

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I have a report (stored procedure) that brings back columns A, B, C, D, E.

Example of the data I retrieve:

```
A                 B         C              D           E
Minnessota        Name1     Oracle         Other data  Other data 
Minnessota        Name1     Microsoft      Other data  Other data
Florida           Name2     Napster        Other data  Other data
Washington        Name3     Stackoverflow  Other data  Other data
```

On this report, I have a sub-report. This sub-report uses the data from a table. Let's call it table Z.

```
SELECT * FROM Z
```

When the main report runs, I need to pass 3 parameters to the sub-report.

The parameters are the distinct values from column A, B, and C of the main report.

How do I set up the sub-report so that when the main report runs, the distinct of A, B, and C are passed as parameters to the sub-report?

So instead of being `SELECT * FROM Z`, it'll be

```
SELECT * FROM Z WHERE Column1 = A AND Column2 = B and Column3 = C
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create 3 multi-valued parameters and set the source query for them as the below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [A] FROM [TABLE] WHERE ....

SELECT DISTINCT [B] FROM [TABLE] WHERE ....

SELECT DISTINCT [C] FROM [TABLE] WHERE ....
```

Add any additional conditions(parameters) in `WHERE` clauses.

Next, for the sub report, keep the dataset query as it is, but add 3 filters instead.

Use the below to have a comma-separated list of values in parameter:

```
Join(Parameters!Param1.Value, ",")
```

That will do the necessary filtering. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd255264.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337293(v=sql.100).aspx) for additional help.